# How can I make screen's statusbar show the windows without the - and $ characters?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I have the following in my .screenrc file

```
hardstatus string '%{= kw}[%{r} %d/%m/%Y %C %A %{w}] [%= %{= kw}%-Lw%{= kW}%{r}%n:%t%?%?%{= kw}%?%+Lw%?%?%= ] [ %{r}%l%{w} ]%{w}%{w}'
```

and the statusbar shows up as

```
[ 30/12/2010  8:24 PM ] [                                       0$ bash  1-$ bash  2:bash                                        ] [ 0.00 0.03 0.04 ]
```

I want it like this instead:

```
[ 30/12/2010  8:24 PM ] [                                       0:bash  1:bash  2:bash                                        ] [ 0.00 0.03 0.04 ]
```

Comment: Is this gnome panel, byobu, what?

Comment: Neither. It's GNU screen

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
hardstatus string '%{= kw}[%{r} %d/%m/%Y %C %A %{w}] [%= %{= kw}%-w%{r}%n:%t%{= kw} %+w%= ] [ %{r}%l%{w} ]'
```

The main thing is to remove the "L" in both places. It is what causes the status characters to be displayed. The colon will only be displayed on the current window. I removed a few extraneous things, too.